# Executing a long-running method right before a page redirect in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a method that is quite data intensive and could take minutes. Here is some code:

```
Data.Common.Documents.Regenerate();
Response.Redirect("~/Members/ManageDocs.aspx");
```

What is the simplest way to execute this method in a background thread?

Comment: do you need to complete `Regenerate` method before `Redirect`?

Comment: no, i just need it started in the background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware, that if your App Domain gets recycled by the IIS, you'll lose the thread and everything that goes with it. But if you're OK with that, you can use [TPL (.NET 4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Data.Common.Documents.Regenerate());
```

That's assuming you don't have to wait for completion, 'cause that would defeat the point of background processing in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

If it will take very long, don't do it in asp.net. Move the processing to a windows service or a scheduled job. Asp.net is not designed for long running jobs.

If you must use asp.net though; you could refactor your code to Redirect without a `ThreadAbortException`, flush the output, and then continue with this

```
Response.Redirect("~/Members/ManageDocs.aspx", false);
Response.Flush();
Data.Common.Documents.Regenerate();
```